# Clipping the top and left of a div contained inside another div

Tags: html, css

With nested divs I'd like to clip the top and left to center the inner div.

```
<div>
<div style="position: relative; top: -160px; left: 10px; width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
<!-- div>
<div style="width: 686px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;" -->
<IFRAME SRC="http://www.aol.com/" FRAMEBORDER="0" BORDER="0" ID="slpane" width="900px" height="900px"></iframe> 
</div>
</div>
```

Having a negative top and left seems to put the inner div over the top and left of the containing div.  How do I keep the div nested while clipping the top and left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent element of the element with a negative `top`.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ3gt/**

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<div style="position: relative; top: -160px; left: 10px; width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
<!-- div>
<div style="width: 686px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;" -->
<IFRAME SRC="http://www.aol.com/" FRAMEBORDER="0" BORDER="0" ID="slpane" width="900px" height="900px"></iframe> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS on the parent element (the one with the negative padding) to include

```
overflow: hidden;
```